# Переход Android проекта на Kotlin на sdk 26+

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, kotlin

Я хочу изменить `targetSdkVersion` моего проекта Android c 25 на 27. Проблема в том, что я использовал Kotlin, но есть некоторые большие изменения:

1) изменилась подпись `View.findViewById()`. Теперь мне нужно использовать `findViewById<View>`

2) `getContext()` фрагмента стал not null safety, поэтому мне нужно добавить !! ко всем значениям контекста во всех фрагментах.

Есть ли способ исправить это автоматически для всего проекта? Это не маленький проект, и для выполнения этих исправлений вручную потребуется много времени.

Comment: 1) не всегда. если у вас явно указан тип View, то передавать его не обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вместо `View.findViewById()` можно воспользоваться Kotlin Android Extensions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html (что намного удобнее)
2. А получить контекст во фрагменте можно обращаясь к переменной `activity`. Например: `startActivity(Intent(activity, SomeActivity::class.java))`
   Ну а исправлять все надо вручную(по крайней мере, я быстрого способа не знаю). Разве что в Android Studio Find and replace **Ctrl + Shift + R**.